# using jQuery ajax with servlet jsp

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp form **validate.jsp** which contains 2 text fields where user enters his/her roll number/name. I have also written some validation code using javascript to verify the input.

Now after collecting the input I forward these two parameters to another page **result.jsp** using jQuery ajax as shown below:

```
$("#student_result").load("result.jsp?"+ $.param( { rollNo: rollNo, name: name }));
```

Now my result.jsp page has to display result of the person whose roll no or name has been entered by the user. So, this **result.jsp** page contains all database logic(java code). But conventionally we should write all the business logic in a servlet. So I want to do this.

But, as you can see, I am loading the contents of **result.jsp** dynamically using ajax inside the **validate.jsp** page. If I use a servlet I need to use requestDispatcher which will forward to and hence load the entire **result.jsp** page!

I don't want to do that! I still want to load **result.jsp** page contents dynamically in the **validate.jsp** page. How to do that?

Or will there be any complications if I keep the entire database logic in **result.jsp** file?

Comment: I don't understand your concrete problem. Just replace `load("result.jsp")` by `load("servletURL")`? What have you actually done in your attempt to use the servlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are better approaches to solve your problem. If you don't want to use a framework I think you should use servlets at least.

If you still want to do it using only jsps your result.jsp should only return the fragment you want to load in you page, and not a whole html page.

Another way to do it is with the next AJAX request:

```
$("#student_result").load("result.jsp .roll", {rollNo: rollNo, name: name });
```

The above will only load the element with the class `roll`.

Comment: Here a only particular fragment of result.jsp would be loaded in validate.jsp page. That's fine! But the question of servlets is still unsolved! Can I still load it dynamically if I use a servlet for all db coding? Can JSON do some help.. I just found something related to JSON while googling around!

Comment: Yes you can (no need for JSON). Still, it's a good practice to split db coding into several servlets. Otherwise your app would be really difficult to maintain if it grows a little.

Comment: How? result.jsp contents would be loaded dynamically then?

Comment: In your result.jsp (I insist, a servlet would be more appropriate for this) you need to run your Java code and select the info you want from your database depending on the parameters you're passing. If you have trouble doing this post some result.jsp code so I can be more helpful.